How do we justify that simplicity and the number of entities are not the main criteria for choosing an explanation?
How do we justify that simplicity or Occam's razor can only be applied when the explanations are equal?
How do we justify that the small number of entities an explanation has does not make the explanation more likely?
Solipsism has a small number of entities, and the existence of other minds has a large number of entities.
We consider solipsism to be false because it does a poor job of explaining our experience.
But solipsism has the fewest entities and is therefore the simplest explanation.
Why do we not consider the small number of entities a reason to believe in solipsism?
Is it because Occam's razor only applies when the explanations are equal?
Solipsism does not explain our experience well, and the existence of other minds explains our experience well, and therefore the explanations are not equally good, and so Occam's razor cannot be applied?
Do we have evidence that a small number of entities in our universe does not affect the probability of an explanation?
Or do we have evidence that the number of entities does not matter in our universe?
Do we have evidence that the number of entities in our universe is not limited?
Is it a subjective choice of each person?
Or do we rely on authorities about what simplicity is important?
Or do we rely on our experience of interaction with the outside world and other people and see that there are no restrictions on the number of entities?

What if everyone believed in solipsism? The universe does seem to have a lot of things in it.

I think we observe from our experience that in our universe there is no reason to consider explanations with fewer entities more likely. But I don't know if this is circular reasoning or if it is reasonable.

Can you explain?

Ok, um, I was being silly, but: in solipsism there is no 'everyone', so it is an absurd statement. But, the first thing that comes to mind nevertheless. Also, 'entity' is often used to mean "sentient being".
